# Angular 7 installation in MVC 5 Issues

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

I have a project i Angular4 and MVC 5 which is running fine.

I wanted to upgrade, so I went package.json in Visual Studio 17 and on every package version I selected the latest version of it using intellisense. I generated me the below mentioned configuration file.

I ran restore packages on this file which provided me many files in node_modules, however it gave some some warning and especially **node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js** file was not generated

Package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "PMS",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.5",
    "angular-compare-validator": "0.2.0",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "1.0.2",
    "angular4-multiselect-dropdown": "2.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.6.5",
    "ng4-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ngx-mydatepicker": "2.4.9",
    "ngx-ssrs-reportviewer": "1.0.2",
    "rxjs": "6.4.0",
    "systemjs": "^3.0.0",
    "systemjs-plugin-babel": "0.0.25",
    "underscore": "1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "11.9.4",
    "angular4-multiselect-dropdown": "2.0.0",
    "http-server": "0.11.1",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "0.15.0",
    "typescript": "3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Issue

1. **node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js** file was not generated

Warnings

> ```
> npm WARN @angular/animations@4.4.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.1.0-10 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.1.0-10 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN karma-jasmine@1.1.2 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN karma-jasmine@1.1.2 requires a peer of karma@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.4.0 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.4.0 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN ng2-bs3-modal@0.15.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN ng2-bs3-modal@0.15.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN ng2-bs3-modal@0.15.0 requires a peer of bootstrap@~3.3.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN ng2-bs3-modal@0.15.0 requires a peer of jquery@1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN PMS@1.0.0 No description
> npm WARN PMS@1.0.0 No repository field.
> npm WARN The package angular4-multiselect-dropdown is included as both a dev and production dependency.
>
> + systemjs@3.0.0
> updated 1 package and audited 301 packages in 25.239s
> found 0 vulnerabilities
> ```

Comment: Completely remove your `node_modules` directory and use `npm install`. Then try to find `animations@4.4.7` in your project directory including node_modules. I belive `ng4-charts` or  `angular4-multiselect-dropdown` can use `@angular/animations@4.4.7`. You have to update them too. And `ng2-bs3-modal` has the same issue but with angular 6. You can't always just upgrade Angular without upgrading your packages.

Comment: have you added "scripts": [ "node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js" ] in your angular .json file?

Comment: animations folder is there \@angular\animations

Comment: where should I add this? "scripts": [ "node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js" ]